# Fetch and open a user specific url stored in a spreadsheet database using Google Apps Script in a Google Site

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sites

I've got an ambitious first Google Apps Script project for use in a Google site.

Using a spreadsheet database I have a list of Google users that each have a unique URL to a service at a non-Google website.

What I need to do is place a link in a Google Site that will

- Get current user id based on logged in user
- Interrogate spreadsheet database for the unique URL based on Google user
- open the unique url in another tab/window

Any pointers or code snippets would be very much appreciated, especially around minimising user authorisation. As it is a Google Apps domain the script could be pre-authorised as a trusted script if that is even possible.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I did write a site gadget that does exactly what you want, (except that users have to enter their name because the site is public and I wanted to avoid asking authorization), you'll find the code and explanations [here](https://sites.google.com/site/appsscriptexperiments/home/this-site-gadgets), I'm not going to reproduce the whole code here but in short it allows to enter a name (even partially) and looks for any match in a spreadsheet list then shows a link to an individual url. It is also possible to see it working on the same page.

[image]
(see page bottom, it looks like this)

To answer your second point, there is no way to avoid the authorization process, the idea of 'trusted source in a domain' has already been mentioned in a few discussions with project members but for now it is not possible.

Comment: Serge, simply awesome. Your project helped immensely.  When it's done (assuming I succeed) I'll let you know the outcome. Many thanks for taking the time out to respond

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'll get it working, this is almost 'plug-and-play' :-)